# MVC 2 jQuery validation & ajax form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to use jQuery ($.post) to submit my html form, but I want to use the client side validation feature of MVC 2.  Currently I hook up the post function to the "OnSubmit" event of the form tag, but I can't hook into the validation, ideally I want to be able to do

```
if (formIsValid) {
     $.post('<%=Url.Action("{some action}")%>'...
}
```

Please note, Client side validation is working with jQuery.validation, I just can't get it to test if the validation was successful or not before I post my data.

Andrew

The final solution

```
<%
    Html.EnableClientValidation();
    using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "registrationForm" })) {
%>
...
<button type="submit" onclick="return submitRegistration();">Register</button>
<%
    }
%>



<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitRegistration() {
    if ($("#registrationForm").valid()) {
      $.post('<%=Url.Action("{some action}")'...
    }
    // this is required to prevent the form from submitting
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can initiate jQuery validation on the button click event. Place the following inside your button-click event-handler:

```
if ($('form').valid())
   //take appropriate action for a valid form. e.g:
   $('form').post('<%=Url.Action("{some action}")%>')
else
   //take appropriate action for an invalid form
```

See the Validation plugin [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) for more information.